# Deprecated Xcode Build issue while sent version from Xcode version 8.3

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, xcode8, appstore-approval

I have recently uploaded a build in AppStore(TestFlight) and got the following mail from AppStore,

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "MY APP". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct
>   the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Deprecated Xcode Build - Due to resolved app archives issues, we will
>   be deprecating Xcode 8.3 on May 10, 2017, at which time app archives
>   built with 8.3 will no longer be accepted by the App Store. Download
>   Xcode 8.3.2 or newer, rebuild your app and resubmit.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application
>   Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Will there be any problem on releasing the current build for review ?

Or
Do I want to download the latest Xcode version as mentioned in the mail and upload an another build ?

Comment: still using Xcode 8.1 and submitting apps to app store lol

Comment: @NikitaPronchik : Nope, I have updated to XCode 9 but I got a comment for 10 month old question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Will there be any problem on releasing the current build for review?`

If you submit your app for review and will be reviewed successfully before the `May 10, 2017`, than you do not need to do anything with you current build.

`Do I want to download the latest Xcode version as mentioned in the mail and upload an another build ?`

You should be updating to the latest Xcode anyway, at least for the sake of having all the latest tools and API's available. If you would like to submit a new build after the `May 10, 2017`, you **have to** update Xcode, rebuild the app and submit a different binary for Apple to review.

Overall, i would recommend to update now, and submit a different build, because you will have to do it anyway in the near future, and your app will not be rejected because of the `Deprecated Xcode Build` issue for sure.

**EDIT:**
Xcode 8.3.2 is available in the App Store.
[image]

Comment: I got this message and I don't even see 8.3.2 in the app store updates tab yet.

Comment: Must be a pretty severe problem if they are forcing an update in 2 weeks.

Comment: it must be one. However, i can see 8.3.2 in the App Store. Attached a screenshot to my answer.

Comment: Is it possible to use Xcode 8.1 or 8.2 after may 10

Comment: No, the letter says 8.3.2 or newer.